# Comparing a predicted order of events to actual order of events

Tags: ranking, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

Sorry about my somewhat limited knowledge of statistics, it's just this is a tad too complex for my knowledge of the subject.

I'm running a competition where entrants are told what events happen, and they have to figure out the order of events. This would look something like, as an example:

1. The dog dies
2. The owner cries
3. The police arrive
4. The boy finds a knife

I'm looking for a way to quantifiably measure their accuracy in predicting the order of events - would this be done using something like Spearman's rho or Kendall's tau (and if so how would this be done best via Scipy), or is there a better way to do it?